# How to plot Eigenvectors in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, differential-equations, eigenvector

I am trying to plot the eigen vectors for my given problem while solving ordinary differential equations(ODE).
I calculated my Eigen values and Eigenvectors as follows:

```
% A is a 2x2 matrix
A = [(-1) (-1);0 (3/4)]  
% calculating Eigenvalues and eigenvectors

s =       eig(A)               
[V,s] =   eig(A)
```

I get the output as

```
 s =

-1.0000         0  
                              %Eigenvalue matrix with columns as Eigenvalue
  0          0.7500
```

and Eigenvector matrix as :

```
V =

1.0000   -0.4961          %Eigenvector matrix with columns as Eigenvectors
     0    0.8682
```

Now i want to plot the above Eigenvectors on the x,y plane. (x,y are also variables of my ODE)

How do i plot the columns(The eigenvectors) of the above matrix V in a single plot?

Help will be really appreciated!

Comment: Could you show your expected outcome regarding `V`?

Comment: I want to plot the columns of V as vectors with arrows on my MATLAB plot